# Python: How to package all necessary modules/Libs into one singleton executable file?

Tags: python-2.7

The running environment is ubuntu 12.04. Most of the time my python script have to import some external libraries or modules before run. When I distribute the script to some other linux machines. I have to install some necessary modules and libraries again.

Is there some way to package all necessary modules into one single python file and running without installing any module? Thanks

Comment: Not exactly on a single file. But `virtualenv` is your friend. Google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine your files to one file. But it bad way. Select from better solutions:

- create [deb-package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29) with all depends. In next times system will automatically install all libraries, will check correct state and will  remove your files.
- using [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)
- get actually version from your [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).

I have wrote script for generating deb-package after commit to our version control system.

Comment: Why it is bad way? If it can run independently, it will save a lot of time on installing necessary modules or libs... But anyway. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: You will update your sources or libraries in future. Do you want update your application manually for all clients?

Comment: Well I say. For my project, all the scripts are for internal use. Thus, an independent package is ideal for me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I have builded deb packages for internal use. And Windows package too (via wine). It just good practice, particularly for Linux.